# Is it possible to do something like multithreading using Node.js? Perhaps socket.io?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I'm trying to build a connector between a ssl client and a unidata structure. Currently I have a 'net' server that drops a file with the request data, and reads the response file back to the client. The problem is that if multiple clients are connected they will all get the same response. I'm wondering what I need to do to make it so that each connected client can get their own packet back?

Basics of what I started with:

```
const cuid = require('cuid')
const net = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0';
const fs = require('fs');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const shell = require('shelljs');

let fileName = ''
let fileContents = ''

let server = net.createServer(onClientConnected);
server.listen(PORT, ADDRESS);
console.log(`Server running on: ${ADDRESS}:${PORT}`);

function onClientConnected(socket) {
  console.log(`New client: ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`);
  socket.destroy();
}

function onClientConnected(socket) { 
//do file manipulation, watch file changes, save file delete files etc..
```

Comment: node is not multi-threaded platform it is single-threaded, event-loop asycnhronous. This is its beauty and difference

Comment: what you ask can be done in node, however you need to include some code in your question so you get a meaningfull answer related to that. Try to include a minimum, verifiable example

Comment: Please edit your question with your example code.